# Can a polynomial not be in the Reals or Complex?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials

I was reading *Undergraduate Algebraic Geometry* by Miles Reid.

and on page 1. It says

> If $k$ is in $\textbf{R}$ or $\textbf{C}$ (which it quite often is).

Now I should state some previous information.

> A variety is (roughly) a locus defined by polynomial equation: 
>   $$ V = \{P \in k^n | \text{f}_i(P) = 0\} \subset k^n $$
>   where $k$ is a field and $\text{f}_i \in k[X_1, \cdots , X_n] $ are polynomials; so for example the plane curves $\textbf{C} : (\text{f}(x,y) = 0) \subset \textbf{R}^2$ or $\textbf{C}^2$

Now the question:

When are polynomials not in either $\textbf{R} \mbox{ or } \textbf{C}$??

Comment: Have you heard of fields of characteristic $p$?

Comment: @KReiser nope, not yet, just found the book at the bookstore and thought it would be a good to study.  Got a good references or book?

Comment: Well, your polynomial could be defined over a field of characteristic $p$, which does not embed into either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. For example, consider $x^2-x-1$ over $\mathbb{F}_3$, the field with 3 elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the point is that the definition of a variety makes sense for any (algebraically closed) field $k$. But for most concrete examples that you will encounter in the class the field will be the real or the complex numbers.

Edit: To add a bit more on "how can a polynomial not be in the reals or the complex" numbers?

There are a lot of other fields than the real and the complex numbers. You can take for example the rational numbers. They also constitute a field.

Consider the finite field $\mathbb{Z} / 3\mathbb{Z}$. This field has three elements: $[0], [1], [2]$ and we have for example that $[2][2] = [4] = [1]$. You can consider polynomials over this field, for example: 
$$
f(x) = [1]X^2 + [2]X.$$
(we will usually write this just as $f(X) = X^2 + 2X$).  The polynomial is not "in the reals or the complex" because the coefficients are not from those fields.

Wikipedia has a page on field with a [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_%28mathematics%29#Examples) of example of different fields.

Comment: So which fields are not in the Reals or Complex, could you give me a name to look up?

Comment: @MaoYiyi: Did my edit help?

Comment: Oh, I get it know.  I was confused because I was thinking along the lines of $x=$ (anything not int he reals) but $x^2+2x$ is in either the Reals or Complex, so how can any polynomial not be in the Reals or Complex.

Comment: @MaoYiyi As listed, it is not true that $x^2+2x$ with coefficients from $\mathbb{F}_3$ is a polynomial with real or complex coefficients, because the coefficients are from $\mathbb{F}_3$, which does not embed into the real or the complex numbers.